# Regex em string dinâmica de X caracteres, em conteúdo dinâmico

Tags: php, string, regex, random

Seguinte, tenho uma página que gera um conteúdo embaralhado com strings dinâmicas e não dinâmicas, preciso pegar um valor dinâmico entre os separadores `|`, o mesmo contem dados/strings aleatórios em volta, que mudam ao carregar a página. A variável que desejo pegar tem um número de caracteres fixo de 32 composta por letras, números e `_` (`a-zA-Z0-9_`).

**Exemplo**:

*CONTEÚDO DA PÁGINA*

```
...new "x";test>'ok'=blabla-bla;||inicio||var77|var2|44AsFGq72A7_7Aq770vAr45|variavel|randomvariavel75|87df".fim("0"...
```

Desejo pegar o valor de `33` caracteres (`44AsFGq72A7_7Aq770vAr45`) mas não sei como pois quando a página é atualizada os valores do lada da string de `23` caracteres mudam de ordem, e a própria string também pois ela é randômica.

*Exemplo atualização da página.*

> (PS: OS valores inicio e fim sempre estão no mesmo lugar)

```
...new "x";test>'ok'=blaalb-bla;||inicio||r_a_n_d99|var2|84DF8|7s79DFGDsf8ssfs84D84d8D|var77|8526".fim("0"...
```

Preciso usar `regex` no `php` para pegar essa variável randômica nessa página randômica excluindo qualquer outro código que possa aparecer.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: A string que queres tem 23,32 ou 33 caracteres?

Comment: Me desculpe pela inconsistência, na verdade são mais de uma, acabei misturando, mas só um exemplo serve para as outras, digamos que tenha 23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = 'new "x";test>\'ok\'=blabla-bla;||inicio||var77|var2|44AsFGq72A7_7Aq770vAr45|variavel|randomvariavel75|87df".fim("0"...';
preg_match_all( '/\|[a-zA-Z0-9_]{23}\|/' , $str , $out );
print_r( $out );
```

Você pode usar `{N}` para definir o comprimento da string que deseja encontrar. No exemplo acima vai encontrar a string de 23 caracteres contendo `a-zA-Z0-9_` que estiver dentre o delimitador `|`.

Output: `44AsFGq72A7_7Aq770vAr45`

[**Exemplo no Ideone**](https://ideone.com/XtnZrK)

Comment: Resolveu perfeitamente, obrigado pelo tempo dedicado, só precisei usar um `str_replace` para remover um valor estático e está perfeito, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Como @PapaCharlie comentou você pode usar o `{N}` para delimitar o numero exato de caracteres de deseja.

Quanto a regex:

Você pode usar o auxiliar `\w` que representa justamente `a-zA-Z0-9_`

`preg_match( '~(?<=\|)(\w{23})(?=\|)~' , $str , $out );`

`(?<=\|)`  auxiliar - deve conter antes, mas não capturar
`(?=\|)`   auxiliar - deve conter depois, mas não capturar

ou simplismente

`preg_match( '~\|(\w{23})\|~' , $str , $out );`
`$var = $out[1];` o valor vai estar no grupo 1;

Comment: Sem duvida são informações valiosas, aprendi um pouco mais, serão de grande ajuda no futuro.